# Having trouble using the react-masonry-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the react-masonry-component: https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component

I have previously used the original masonry plugin with JQuery but I am completely new to ReactJs and it's code structure. I have added the example code given in the component's documentation but not sure how to get it to work. I am trying to figure out how to add elements to the masonry grid and how to refactor this code to ES6.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import styles from './Works.css';
import withStyles from '../../../../decorators/withStyles';
import Button from '../../../Button';

var Masonry = require('react-masonry-component')(React);

var masonryOptions = {
    transitionDuration: 0
};

@withStyles(styles)
class Works extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var childElements = this.props.elements.map(function(element){
       return (
          <li className="WorkItem">
              <img src={element.src} />
          </li>
        );
    });
    return (
      <div className="Works">
        <h3>Works</h3>
        <Masonry
            className={'WorkList'}
            elementType={'ul'}
            options={masonryOptions}
            disableImagesLoaded={false}>
            {childElements}
        </Masonry>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Works;
```

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined
   at Works.render (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/build/webpack:/src/components/ProfilePage/Layout/Works/Works.js:16:45)
   at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:546:34)
   at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:566:32)
   at [object Object].wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
   at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:181:32)
   at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
   at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
   at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:185:34)
   at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
   at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (/Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
```

I am using React 0.14.0-beta3

Any help very much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to react and had the same problem a few days ago. After reading [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), it became clear to me. The **map** method is simply the **Array.map** method called on an array. The problem in your case is that **this.props.elements** is undefined since it hasn't been set.

Here is a small example where the data is set correctly.

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({ 

    render() {
        var Masonry = require('react-masonry-component')(React);

        var MyCard = React.createClass({

            render() {
                return (
                    <div style={{padding:'1em'}}>
                        <div style={{border:'1px solid black', width:'100px', height:'100px'}}>
                            {this.props.title}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }

        });

        var MyGallery = React.createClass({

            render() {

                var children = this.props.cards.map(function(card) {
                   return (
                        <MyCard title={card.title}/>
                    );
                });

                return (
                    <Masonry className={'my-gallery-class'} elementType={'ul'} options={{}} disableImagesLoaded={false}>
                        {children}
                    </Masonry>
                );
            }
        });

        var cards = [
            { title: 'A'},
            { title: 'B'},
            { title: 'C'},
            { title: 'D'},
            { title: 'E'},
            { title: 'F'}
        ];

        return (
            <div>
                <MyGallery cards={cards}/>
            </div>

        );
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

The **react-masonry-component** seems like a nice and easy component to use but I can't find any documentation of what it can do.

BTW: You will get a warning from react when running this code since the items aren't keyed. You may want to read up on http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **this.props.elements** is not defined in, so you can´t call the map function on it.

Have you tried using the react dev-tools? You can inspect the **works** component with the tools and see, which props are defined in each component.

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

My guess is that you are not passing the correct variable into the components **elements** prop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options here. One would be use `this.props.children`.

This means you could nest the elements in a Gallery component like so:

```
<Gallery>
  <img src="SOME_URL" />
  <img src="SOME_URL" />
  <img src="SOME_URL" />
</Gallery>
```

Then in your Gallery component class is where you would use `this.props.children`.

```
class Gallery extends Components({
  render()
    return (
      <Masonry>
        { this.props.children }
      </Masonry>
    );
  }
});
```

---

Another option would be to just remove the `this.props.` from `this.props.elements` where `childElements` is being assigned. Then above that assign the `elements` variable to an array of objects that have a `src` prop.

```
class Gallery extends Component {
  render() {
    const elements = [{src: 'URL'}, {src: 'URL'}, {src: 'URL'}]

    const childElements = elements.map((element, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index}>
          <img src={element.src} />
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Masonry>
        {childElements}
      </Masonry>
    );
  }
}
```