# React masonry returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im working with the plugin [react-masonry-component](https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component) im trying to convert it to es6 but I cant seem to get past the rendering of elements as it is always `undefined`

Here is my code below of what I have so far. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-component';

const masonryOptions = {
  transitionDuration: 0
};

class MasonryWidget extends Component {
    render() {
        const childElements = this.props.elements.map(function(element){
           return (
                <li className="image-element-class">
                    <img src={element.src} />
                </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <Masonry
                className={'my-gallery-class'}
                elementType={'ul'}
                options={masonryOptions}
                disableImagesLoaded={false}
                updateOnEachImageLoad={false}
            >
                {childElements}
            </Masonry>
        );
    }
};

export default MasonryWidget;
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console ? from where you are passing the data `this.props.elements` can you show that component ?

Comment: Its just a bare component for the most part my error is `TypeError: this.props.elements is undefined` then i import it into my container element

Comment: then instead of `this.props.element` define an `array` in this component like this: `a = [{}, {}, {}]` and each object should contain a key src with image url, it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

The map method is actually the Array.map method called on an array.

In your case is the this.props.elements would be undefined if it hasn't been set.

I had a similar issue in the past and this SO answer helped clear it up:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498429/5760421